# jquery modal popup fixed when scrolling UP DATED

Tags: jquery

I have a web page that scrolls, in the code I have a script that loads a Jquery mopdal popup window when all the items on the page have been selected. This works fine. But, I need the popup window to be fixed in the center of the screen if the user continues to scroll up or down. This script that loads the popup is:

```
$('#complete').show();
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#backbutton2').hide();
var $scrollingDiv = $("#complete");
$("#complete").attr('title','Audit complete').dialog({
  modal: true,
  autoOpen: true,
  width : 400,
  height: 220,
    buttons: {
        'Finish': function () {
        $(this).dialog("Finish");
        window.location.href = "close_room.php?UniqueID=<?php print $_SESSION['UniqueID'] ;?>"; 
         }
    }
}); 
$(window).scroll(function(){            
$scrollingDiv
.stop()
.animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 0) + "px"}, "slow" );           
});
});
```

As is, when the popup opens the popup will follow the scroll but the top of the popup window remains fixed while the window it's self grows in length as I scroll down. Can anyone see where I am going wrong.

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the popup, change the css overflow property to hidden like

```
$('body').css('overflow','hidden')
```

When you close it, change back to normal

```
$('body').css('overflow','auto')
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for yur reply. That did not work. After selecting all the items on the page the popup is displayed but at the top and not in the center of the screen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have worked this out with the following code:

```
$('#complete').show();
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#backbutton2').hide(); 
  oDetail  = $("#complete").attr('title','Audit complete').dialog({  
    autoOpen: true,  
    width: 400,  
    height: 220,  
    position: 'center',  
    resizable: 'false',  
    draggable: true,
    buttons: {
        'Finish': function () {
           $(this).dialog("Finish");
           window.location.href = "close_room.php?UniqueID=<?php print $_SESSION['UniqueID'] ;?>"; 
         }
    }
   }); 
$(window).scroll(function () {  
  oDetail .dialog("option","position","center");  
}); 
});
```

I hope this may be of some help to others.